# Trouble rendering objects from Axios call after using React hook

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, axios, react-props

I am attempting to retrieve data from my backend (Mongo) and render it in the front-end (react) but there seems to be some weird behavior surrounding the hook I have created, where it recognizes the 4 objects coming in, but sees them as undefined, before eventually truly seeing the 4 objects and their contents, but at that point, it has already tried unsuccessfully to render them (due to being undefined) and causes the front-end to go blank. Check out browser console to see what I am saying: (Please ignore the warning, it is unrelated)

[image: console]

Here are the important files:

`home.jsx`

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Articles from "../components/articles";

export default function Home() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArticles = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/posts");
      setArticles(res.data);
    };
    fetchArticles();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Articles articles={articles} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`articles.jsx`

```
export default function Articles({ articles }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(articles[0])}
      {console.log(articles[1])}
      {console.log(articles[2])}
      {console.log(articles[3])}
      {articles[1].title} //here is where the error occurs
    </div>
  );
}
```

I should mention the backend json object is an 'article' that contains 3 fields 'description', 'title', and 'author'.

So, I have tried many things, using try catches around the rendered components, and using a variety of styles for the hook. It seems to me like it is some sort of race case, where the articles.jsx tries to render the component before all the data in retrieved from it, but I can't seem to find a solution to this. I say this because, on occasion, the browser will actually successfully render article, but refresh the page or restart and then it fails again.

Answer (score 0):

Well: the problem appears during the first render: `Articles` component is rendered with an empty array, but you try to access `articles[1].title` which cause an error : you are trying to access a property on `undefined`.

I would do this:

```
export default function Articles({ articles }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {articles.map(article => <div>{article.title}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or use a conditional statement: `articles[1]?.title` (equivalent to `articles[1] && articles[1].title`).

Comment: Thanks, this tutorial also helped a lot for anyone having similar issues: https://dev.to/darkmavis1980/fetching-data-with-react-hooks-and-axios-114h